# Export DOORS attribute font color to Excel font color

Tags: export-to-excel, ibm-doors

I've seen the discussion in  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7981c520-ee1b-4a5f-b1f7-510172d2a3bd&ps=25  and have a copy of the [GalacticSolutions](http://www.galactic-solutions.com/downloads/GalacticDownloadExcel.htm) Excel export script.  That script takes the color of the font in a module cell and maps it to the Excel cell-fill color.  What isn't clear to me is how to take that same source color and map it instead to the Excel cell's  text color.
My source attribute is an enumeration with the assigned colors setting the font color as in    [image: this picture] .    Perhaps the simplest answer that would help me is if someone familiar with the GalacticSolutions script ,   , could identify the code which passes the color to the cell fill-color and provide the equivalent command to handle the font color.
thanks
Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer on an IBM forum and am copying it here.

```
dowhich = "Interior"  //to shade the cell
dowhich = "Font" //to color the font

void excelSetRangeColorOLE( OleAutoObj objExcelRange, int iRGBValue ) { OleAutoObj objExcelInterior = null oleResult( oleGet( objExcelRange, dowhich, objExcelInterior ) ) oleResult( olePut( objExcelInterior, "Color", iRGBValue ) ) }
```